# get array [0] does not work on webserver (online) local it does work

Tags: php, oop

I have made a DB class and added some methods. All works fine local but online it gives a error of a unexpected [

this is the code

```
public function results() {
    return $this->_results;
}


public function first() {
     return $this->results()[0]; //this line causes errors ?
}
```

the server is running PHP Version 5.3.27 so my first tought would be thats ok ?

Comment: 5.4 feature http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php. You can use `return reset($this->results());` to keep it a one-liner

Comment: Of course this is **not** OK, this syntax is available from php 5.4

Comment: From the manual: `As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments said, this is the feature of PHP 5.4. In previous PHP versions you have to use the following code:

```
public function first() {
   return current($this->results());  
}
```

[`current`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.current.php) function returns the element indicated by internal array pointer. That is the first one in the case of "fresh" array.

If you don't want to rely on that, use the `_result` field:

```
public function first(){
   return $this->_results[0];
}
```